# How to trigger a click on a date in jquery UI Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Jquery ui calender.How to trigger a click on a date and display date when I click on a specific date using javascript or jquery

Comment: What did you tried so far ?

Comment: Show some code what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It will Help you.

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

Comment: I already have a datepicker. I need to call a function on click of a date in the datepicker

Answer (score 0):

This is simple example for **Datepicker**.

```js
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

Comment: I already have a datepicker.I want to call a function on click of a date in the datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Html

```
Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

Script:

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
     onClose: function(){
        validate($(this).val());
     }
});

function validate(dateText){
     try {
         alert("You selected is : "+ $.datepicker.parseDate('mm/dd/yy',dateText));
         } 
     catch (e) {
         alert("invalid date");
      }; 
    }
```

Comment: Sorry.It dint answer my question.Because it opens a datepicker when i click on a input field.But  my requirement is to click on date when the date picker is already available.

Comment: Yes, In that the datepicker is alerady available and when u select particular date, it call  a new function.

Comment: [Are you mean like that?](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#icon-trigger)

Comment: <div id="datepicker" datetest></div> this is my div.and datetest is the directive which calls the jquery ui datepicker

Comment: So, when i load the page it displays the datepicker.and clicking on date in the datepicker should give me that date

Comment: Check this too:
  $("#datepicker").datepicker( {
     onSelect: function(date) {
        alert(date)
     },
    selectWeek: true,
    inline: true,
    startDate: '01/01/2000',
    firstDay: 1,
  });